# How to pick the correct path of artifacts after deploying to deployment group in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I deploy an artifact ZIP file and want to unzip it afterwards. The pipeline looks like this:
[image]

The first step downloads the artifact to this path:

```
C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\worker-ASP.NET Core-CI\drop\worker.zip
```

but the zip Task looks for the zip file in this path:

```
C:\azagent\A2\_work\_tasks\Unzip_31f040e5-e040-4336-878a-59a473334434\1.2.3\*.zip
```

I know there are some hidden variables i can use to give the correct path to the unzip task. Where can i see the variables set for my release task and which one would contain "C:\azagent\A2_work\r2\a\worker-ASP.NET Core-CI\drop\" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default artifact location is stored in one of these variables:

```
$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/{artifact-alias}
$(Pipeline.Workspace)/{artifact-alias}
```

and artifacts are placed in a subdirectory with the artifact alias (the name you gave the alias).

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---general-artifact

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way i can inspect theese variables before, during or after runtime of the pipeline? Or do i have to debug by trial&error?

Comment: Mostly trial & error. But there is some cool stuff that can help: https://github.com/DarqueWarrior/vsteam/blob/master/docs/Test-VSTeamYamlPipeline.md

Comment: But not in UI mode, you'll have to switch to YAML for that.

Comment: you can also turn on diagnostics mode for your pipeline, most values will be logged to the task-log in that case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops